# Python ide thonny installation error in ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am facing the below issue while installing thonny ide for python.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/shrivatsa/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/thonny/workbench.py", line 287, in _init_runner runner.start()
File "/home/shrivatsa/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/thonny/running.py", line 67, instart self.reset_backend()
File "/home/shrivatsa/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/thonny/running.py", line 427, in reset_backend self._proxy = backend_class(configuraration_option) 
File "/home/shrivatsa/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/thonny/running.py", line 596, in __init__ self._start_new_process()
File "/home/shrivatsa/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/thonny/running.py", line 762, in _start_new_process my_env["JEDI_LOCATION"] = self_prepare_jedi()
File "/home/shrivatsa/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/thonny/running.py", line 703, in _prepare_jedi import jedi ImportError: No module named 'jedi'
```

The application launches but no run button and dedug button is active.

Comment: I do agree that normally, but for example with this code formatting improves the readability a lot. The other one was just a mess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message shows you are missing the module named "jedi".

Try to install it before installing the IDE:

```
pip install jedi
```

Comment: Installing collected packages: parso, jedi
Successfully installed jedi-0.12.1 parso-0.3.1  after this also the same error  message

Answer (score 0):

According to [Thonny blog](https://thonny.org/blog/), this IDE uses [Jedi](https://jedi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (autocompletion/static analysis library). So make sure it also installed (via `pip`, for example).

Comment: For those who kindle provided minuses - sometimes you see NO answers while writing your own and after you submit the answer, boom, someone already answered.